# how to set name for an interactive buffer in elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have the following function defined in emacs -

```
(defun web2py-server ()
 (interactive)
 (shell-command "cd /opt/web2py; python /opt/web2py/web2py.py &"))
```

The above creates a new buffer in emacs, how do set a name "abc" for the window.

Thanks,
Murtaza

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `shell-command`'s second parameter, `OUPTUT-BUFFER`, for that:

```
(defun web2py-server ()
 (interactive)
 (shell-command "cd /opt/web2py; python /opt/web2py/web2py.py &"
                (get-buffer-create "abc")))
```

Comment: I didn't think of using get-buffer-create as the output-buffer argument. That's a tidy answer.

Comment: Mortiz thanks for the reply. So is the output of the shell command being routed to to the get-buffer-create function ?

Comment: No. The output is sent to the buffer object given as the second argument in the call to `shell-command`. Now before `shell-command` itself is executed the function `get-buffer-create` is executed which returns a buffer called `abc`, creating it if it doesn't exist prior. So: First, the buffer is created, and that buffer object is passed to `shell-command`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it interactively by calling `M-x rename-buffer`, or you can add the name to your function:

```
(defun web2py-server () 
  (interactive) 
  (shell-command "cd /opt/web2py; python /opt/web2py/web2py.py &")
  (rename-buffer "abc"))
```

Edit:

If you want an ongoing, interactive process, it might be better to use `start-process` instead of `shell-command`. This allows you to designate the output buffer when you start the process. Otherwise, Moritz' answer looks better than my original. If you're interested in start-process, you could start by replacing your `shell-command` line with the following:

```
(let ((default-directory "/opt/web2py"))
  (start-process "my-server" "abc" "python" "/opt/web2py/web2py.py")
```

Comment: For me `shell-command` does not switch to the new buffer, therefore your `rename-buffer` would probably rename the wrong one. Maybe you'd be better off creating the buffer yourself and handing over its name to `shell-command` as its `OUTPUT-BUFFER` parameter?

Comment: Tyler thanks for the answer. What do you mean by start-process lets you designate the output buffer ?. Also why do you have the default-directory call enclosed in two brackets ?

Comment: The second argument to start-process s the buffer name to use for process output. I used let to temporarily redefine default-directory, the brackets are part of let syntax.